# How to reduce the overhead of loop when measuring the performance?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling

When I try to measure the performance of a piece of code, I put it into a loop and iterate for a million time.

```
for i: 1 -> 1000000
{
    "test code"
}
```

But by using profiling tools, I found that the overhead of the loop is so big that it impacts the performance result significantly, especially when the piece of code is small, say, 1.5s of total elapsed time with 0.5s of loop overhead.

So I'd like to know if there is a better way to test the performance? Or should I stick to this method, but make multiple pieces of the same code under the same loop to increase its weight in the performance?

```
for i: 1 -> 1000000
{
    "test code copy 1"
    "test code copy 2"
    "test code copy 3"
    "test code copy 4"
}
```

Or is it OK to subtract loop overhead off the total time? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good compiler would unroll the loop to some extent. What kind of tasks are you benchmarking?

Comment: @E_net4 I'm testing the expression template. I checked the assembly but found it was not unrolled even when the expression is small, say A+B.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what flags have you tried?

Comment: @E_net4 I'm using gcc 4.8.3 with "-Wall -g -O2(or-O3) -std=c++11" flags.

Comment: I suggest using 1.0E+09 iterations due to the speed of modern processors.  Remember also, that there are other things that may get in the way of your profiling:  other programs executing, waiting on I/O, memory or databus sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at the assembly listing generated by the compiler.  Count the number of instructions in the overhead.

Usually, for an incrementing loop, the overhead consists of:

1. Incrementing loop counter.
2. Brancing to top of loop.
3. Comparison of counter to limit.

On many processors, these are one processor instruction each or close to that.  So find out the average time for an instruction to exit, multiply by the number of instructions in the overhead and that becomes your overhead time for one iteration.

For example, on a processor that averages 100ns per instruction and 3 instructions for the overhead, each iteration uses 3 * (100ns) or 300ns per iteration.  Given 1.0E6 iterations, 3.0E08 nanoseconds will be due to overhead.  Subtract this quantity from your measurements for a more accurate measurement of the loop's content.